# How to return the values from iOS to javascript in Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I am unable to pass the result or return the value from native iOS to javascript in Cordova 1.7.0. Thanx in advance..

Comment: You'll find people more willing to help if you can show what you've already tried and what happened/how it was different from what you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can code in native iOS.

Eg.

```
-(void) onClose {

       NSString* jsCallback = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ChildBrowser._onClose(%d);",am.setPage];
       [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallback];
}
```

Then code in "childbrowser.js" file,

Code:

```
ChildBrowser._onClose = function(getPg)
{
    window.localStorage.setItem("setPage", getPg);

    window.plugins.childBrowser.onClose();
};
```

Then, you can get in javascript file whenever you need.

Eg.

```
var page = window.localStorage.getItem("setPage");
```

By this way,

You can get values from native to js code by using plug-ins.

Thanks.

Comment: hi , did this code work for you  is there anythin else needed to be done here ?